# Paging in Devexpress XtraGrid GrdiControl for Windows Application

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

How do I do paging in devexpress gridcontrol for c# windows application

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "paging" ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Server Mode
http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraGrid/CustomDocument2990.htm&levelup=true